# Remove в цикле

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Есть лист. Нужно проверить каждую строку, если она равна "none" - удалить её.

Во время выполнения кода, представленного ниже, происходит **Fatal Error**.
Всё из-за данного блока кода:

```
if (lv_arr.get(i).equals("none")){
                        lv_arr.remove(i);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Если подставить вместо переменной **i** цифру,то всё работает отлично,а мне нужно в цикле проверить каждую запись листа.

```
ArrayList<String> lv_arr = new ArrayList<String>(key);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

              for (i = 0; i < key; i++){
                lv_arr.add(Pref.getString("n" + i, "none"));

                if (lv_arr.get(i).equals("none")){
                    lv_arr.remove(i);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вообще сначала добавлять строку, а затем тут же её удалять? Тут проблема в алгоритме - ты добавляешь строку, если она не нужна, сразу же её удаляешь, но при этом счётчик у тебя всё равно увеличивается, и при следующей итерации ты уже попытаешься удалить несуществующую строку...

Писать надо как-то так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < key; i++) {
    String someValue = Pref.getString("n" + i, "none");
    if (!someValue.equals("none")) {
        lv_arr.add(someValue);
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Вызывать уведомление адаптера в цикле тоже ни к чему, лучше один раз после цикла вызвать.